# Why is my code repeating itself while computing?

Tags: java

[image: Compilation]

When I run my code it outputs the print part 2 times instead of one and I couldnt understand the reason behind it.I think it counts ENTER as a character but ı dont know how to prevent that

```
public class DoWhile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        char ch;
        do {
            System.out.print("Press a key followed by ENTER : ");
            ch = (char)System.in.read(); // get a char
        } while (ch != 'q');

    }
}
```

Comment: Code, error messages and program output are text. Please [edit] your question and post them as such.

Comment: I'd use `java.util.Scanner` to read characters rather than a simple `System.in.read()` ; pretty sure you're reading the linefeeds you input when pressing enter after each letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.in.read()` is reading a character at a time.

When you enter say `n` and then "Enter" on your keyboad it reads those two characters but one at a time.
First `n` is read, the while loop completes and goes on, then "Enter" aka linefeed is read and it continue as its a control character you don't see anything on screen.

Comment: Is there a way to overcome this issue without using Scanner class ? Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: You can fix it by adding ``System.in.read(new byte[System.in.available()])`` at the end of the while loop, which basically just tells it to read in as many characters/bytes as it can before asking for input again.

Comment: you can also read lines, by decorating the input stream. `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` on this br you can do a `br.readLine()`

Answer (score 1):

Because when you enter a character and then press enter. Enter is also one of the characters returned to you. From within the debugger, set a break point on the while line. Look at the characters being sent to you. You will see first the letter typed, then the /n character.